# Hostnames in HAProxy configuration file

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, hostname, hosts

My haproxy.cfg file has two backend servers using hostnames:

```
server ops-ca-revealv2e-prod-1 ops-ca-revealv2e-prod-1:443 cookie ops-ca-revealv2e-prod-1 ssl weight 1 maxconn 512 check

server ops-ca-revealv2e-prod-2 ops-ca-revealv2e-prod-2:443 cookie ops-ca-revealv2e-prod-2 ssl weight 1 maxconn 512 check
```

These hostnames are part of Amazon OpsWorks and are injected into /etc/hosts automatically whenever an instance comes up or down. If I attempt to restart HAProxy when one of the instances is down, I receive the error:

```
[ALERT] 362/225440 (27202) : parsing [/opt/haproxy-ssl/haproxy.cfg:42] : 'server ops-ca-revealv2e-prod-2' : invalid address: 'ops-ca-revealv2e-prod-2' in 'ops-ca-revealv2e-prod-2:443'
[ALERT] 362/225440 (27202) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /opt/haproxy-ssl/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 362/225440 (27202) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

Is there a way to tell HAProxy to check if a hostname is valid? If it is valid, use it, if not, ignore it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In haproxy >= 1.7, you should be able to use the `init-addr` option, specifying none to prevent DNS resolution at startup.

From the [docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#init-addr):

`init-addr {last | libc | none | <ip>},[...]*`

> Indicate in what order the server's address should be resolved upon startup
>   if it uses an FQDN. Attempts are made to resolve the address by applying in
>   turn each of the methods mentionned in the comma-delimited list. The first
>   method which succeeds is used. If the end of the list is reached without
>   finding a working method, an error is thrown. Method "last" suggests to pick
>   the address which appears in the state file (see "server-state-file"). Method
>   "libc" uses the libc's internal resolver (gethostbyname() or getaddrinfo()
>   depending on the operating system and build options). Method "none"
>   specifically indicates that the server should start without any valid IP
>   address in a down state. It can be useful to ignore some DNS issues upon
>   startup, waiting for the situation to get fixed later. Finally, an IP address
>   (IPv4 or IPv6) may be provided.

So your config line could be:

`server s1 myhostname init-addr none`

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible from within haproxy.

According to the manual, the `address` in the `server` configuration line is

> [...]
>   the IPv4 or IPv6 address of the server. Alternatively, a resolvable hostname
>   is supported
>   [...]

in other words, it is not allowed to use non-resolvable hostnames in the configuration.

Idea:

> Any part of the address string may reference any number of environment
>   variables by preceding their name with a dollar sign ('$') and
>   optionally enclosing them with braces ('{}'), similarly to what is
>   done in Bourne shell.